# Linear Gitlab update path on Ubuntu?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Our 'guy' who maintained Gitlab (CE) for us has left.  He left good instructions and I've done it before - a long time ago - but to re-dip my toes in the water I want to exercise the utmost care until I become more confident.

[I was looking here at the general instructions](https://about.gitlab.com/update/#ubuntu)

We are on 13.9.1.  I believe the current level will be 13.9.4 if I take the automatic option.  Should I do this or take a manual process where I step-wise update to 13.9.2 -> 13.9.3 -> 13.9.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Gitlab upgrade recommendations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/policy/maintenance.html#upgrade-recommendations), it's safe to upgrade minor and patch versions of the same major version:

> It is considered safe to jump between patch versions and minor
> versions within one major version

And for the [major version upgrade recommendations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrading-to-a-new-major-version) :

> Upgrading the major version requires more attention.
> Backward-incompatible changes and migrations are reserved for major
> versions. We cannot guarantee that upgrading between major versions
> will be seamless. It is suggested to upgrade to the latest available
> minor version within your major version before proceeding to the next
> major version. Doing this will address any backward-incompatible
> changes or deprecations to help ensure a successful upgrade to the
> next major release. Identify a supported upgrade path.

So upgrading from 13.9.1 to 13.9.4 can be done without worries (patch version upgrade). But if you want to upgrade the major version, you've to upgrade to the latest minor version of the former version before upgrading